# ApplicationInsights: How to query full trace of azure function executions containing errors?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I want to use Application Insights to analyse the logging output of my Azure Functions.  If the logging output of a function execution contains at least one error, I want to see the whole logging output of that execution.

Starting point:

```
traces 
| where severityLevel == 3
| where operation_Name == "MyFunctionName" 
| project timestamp, operation_Name, message
```

But this only provides the errors themselves but not the other output of the function executions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Azure Functions V1:**

```
traces 
| where severityLevel == 3
| where operation_Id != ""
| where operation_Name == "MyFunctionName" 
| project operation_Name , operation_Id, severityLevel    
| join (traces | project timestamp, operation_Id,  message ) on operation_Id 
| project timestamp, operation_Name, operation_Id, message
```

All lines with the same operation_Id belong to one function execution.

**For Azure Functions V2:**

```
traces 
| extend invocationId = tostring(customDimensions.InvocationId)
| where severityLevel == 3
| where invocationId != ""
| where operation_Name == "MyFunctionName" 
| project operation_Name, severityLevel, invocationId    
| join (traces |extend invocationId = tostring(customDimensions.InvocationId)| project timestamp, invocationId,  message ) on invocationId  
| project timestamp, operation_Name, message, invocationId
```

All lines with the same invocationId belong to one function execution.

Comment: Please accept this as a answer so that it will help others in the community.